# I am getting this warning. "This app does not meet the Google Play permissions policy relating to the use of SMS or CALL_LOG."

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games, google-play-console

I am getting this warning.

> This app does not meet the Google Play permissions policy relating to
>   the use of SMS or CALL_LOG. You must fix this before 9 March 2019 or
>   your app will be removed from Google Play. Note: if you have recently
>   made a change, it can take up to 12 hours to update this message.

I am not using any permission for sms or call. even my manifest do not have READ_PHONE_STATE permission. But still I am getting this warning.

Comment: `if you have recently made a change, it can take up to 12 hours to update this message` did you wait 12 hours?

Comment: @derHugo i have not made any change since last 6 days. and this warning came yesterday.

Comment: Probably it is already gone already. I got the same message yesterday.

Comment: I think you have the same issue with this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638861/why-i-am-receiving-warning-this-app-does-not-meet-google-play-permissions-poli). It says that you are receiving this warning because somehow directly or indirectly you are using some permissions which does not meet the Google Play permissions policy. Kindly check the answers offered by the developers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I am receiving Warning - this app does not meet Google Play permissions policy, even though my latest version doesn't require these permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638861/why-i-am-receiving-warning-this-app-does-not-meet-google-play-permissions-poli)

Comment: @IshfaqAhmad did you find any solution ? I'm also getting this warning.

Answer (score 1):

It is very unlikely that you are getting this warning even though you don't have these permissions. So there are two possibilities:

1. You do have the permissions even though you think you don't.
2. One of your APKs you have forgotten about has these permissions, even though your main app doesn't.

For case (1), you should look at what permissions your APK requires. You can do this on the command line of your computer. do

```
aapt d permissions "MyApp.apk"
```

This will print all the permissions that are there. If your App does ask for permissions you didn't expect it to, you will need to look at 3rd party libraries your app includes to see if you inherited any permissions from the library.

For case (2), have a look at any Alpha, Beta or testing tracks you have for your app in the Play console. It is possible that an old APK on one of these tracks is asking for the permission and you haven't removed it.

If both of these are not the case, then it might be a bug in the Google Play console. If this is the case, you should contact Google Play support via the help menu.

Comment: Thank you so much. i have done these steps. but still could found any solution. so now i have sent a mail to google. hoping for their positive reply.